# Cannot run program Access is denied while attempting to get adb version Error while Android Application Running

Tags: android, adb

I have downloaded Latest Eclipse, and ADT plugin for android development,and
I have installed jdk-7 added all plugins as per the instructions given in android development site.
I am able to create Android project,I have created sample virtual device(Emulator)

But my project is not building correctly R.java class is not creating
It giving this error in console

[2013-03-21 23:40:51 - adb] Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "H:\eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied' while attempting to get adb version from 'H:\eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'

I am using Windows 7, search in google and given adb.exe path in environment variable still its not fixed.

I am using Android Developer Tools eclipse ADT plugins installed
Android SDK manager 21.1

Please guide me to fix this problem :)

Comment: Go to the directory where SDK is installed i.e. `/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools` and use following command `chmod +x adb`. Also check whether "Debugging" option is enabled in your device settings.

Comment: I am using windows 7 os boss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are installed plugins and all correctly and your not able to build projects that means something is blocking you adb.exe.

Most probably it will be your Antivirus or Firewall.
Disable it and check.

Comment: Thanks man I have uninstalled my antivirus then got worked correctly

Answer (score 2):

This error can also appear because of Permissions issues. Right-click platform-tools folder in your Android SDK folder and in Security tab make sure "All" can Read and Execute.
I've come across this problem sometimes after updating the Android SDK tools in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

yeah its due to your firewall or anti-virus...pause them or better uninstall them.

Comment: This should be comment not answer