# AVD not running

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, android-service

Today when I was doing my project using android studio, a blue screen suddenly appears and system get restarted automatically. And now when I tried to run my app using emulator, the AVD is not running and I get an error as below. Anyone faced this before ? How do I fix this?

> ProcessNotCreatedException: Unexpected error while launching AVD: 
>   Cannot run program
>   "C:\Users\tongws\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe":
>   CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the
>   version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system
>   information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit)
>   version of the program, and then contact the software publisher

[image]

Wnen I click the Android Device Monitor, nothing happen also...

Comment: Can you share the properties of your avd it looks like you can use x86

Comment: But before my laptop get restarted it can launch

Comment: @PedroAGSantos done...please have a look

Comment: no one faced this before except me. :(

Comment: Can you create a new AVD , if so, does it work?

Comment: which AVD ? Nexus 6?

Comment: I get `Throwable: Failed to create the SD card.`

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a virus.

Comment: What? I have uninstalled and reinstall back...the error still there!!!

Comment: I would suggest to reinstall JDK be careful of the JDK you should have

Comment: I have reinstall android studio, but the problem did not fixed

Comment: @Hoo I'm talking about JDK please check that

Comment: OP's computer BSOD'ed... it's not a JDK problem folks.

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/

Comment: Between,why you so sure I have a virus

Comment: @Hoo computers dont' just BSOD for no reason. It's not a coincidence your programs stopped working afterwards. You either have a virus, or a hardware problem - and the virus is a much easier one to deal with. So start there. If your machine comes up clean (and it usually doesn't, even if the user insists it's clean and runs anti-virus), then move onto diagnosing hardware. Either way, you have a computer problem not related to AVD.

Comment: use genymotion instead of AVD this is lightweight and 70%faster then AVD

Comment: and to open Android Device Monitor start android studio as Administrator privileges not from shortcut

Comment: please put snap of AVD settings

Comment: @Survivor I have put it before `When I click....`

Comment: Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) install this from sdk manager and Enable Verbalization from BIOS

Comment: @Survivor how to  Enable Verbalization ?

Comment: sorry not verblization it's virtualization see this link http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware

Comment: Lol..finally it runs after install HAXM installer and Android sdk tools..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have a computer problem not related to AVD

**`ProcessNotCreatedException`** :***Exception thrown when attempting to retrieve the result of a task that aborted by throwing an exception***.

> Because of their usefulness and ubiquity, EXE files are commonly used
>   as a method of delivery for virus / malware infection. Often, viruses
>   will be disguised as a benign EXE file (such as emulator.exe) and
>   distributed through SPAM email or malicious websites, which can then
>   infect your computer when executed (eg. when you double-click the EXE
>   file). In addition, viruses can infect, replace, or corrupt existing
>   EXE files, which can then lead to error messages when 
>   related programs are executed. Thus, any executable files that you
>   download to your PC should be scanned for viruses before opening -
>   even if you think it is from a reputable source.

Read [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532109/cannot-run-program-access-is-denied-while-attempting-to-get-adb-version-error-wh) Answer .

### What should you do

- **FORMAT** Your System
- Install ***Android Studio*** (Set Latest Version With Proper JDK Path)**Note that you need to have JDK 6 or higher installed**.
- You can use `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` or **Genymotion** .

> IF YOU HAVE MULTIPLE DRIVES, THE DRIVE WHERE THE OS IS INSTALLED IS
>   NEEDED TO BE FORMATTED, SO YOU SHALL LOSS ALL DATA OF THAT DRIVE. I
>   SUGGEST YOU TO TAKE A BACK UP OF ALL YOUR IMPORTANT DATA STORED IN
>   THAT DRIVE, INTO OTHER DRIVES WHICH WOULD REMAIN UNCHANGED. ON THE
>   OTHER HAND, IF YOU HAVE ONLY ONE DRIVE, THEN ALL YOUR DATA WILL GET
>   ERASED WHILE FORMATTING .

[image]

Comment: Try this way .I hope it will helps you .

Comment: I reinstall the android studio, but still same. Between, when I click Android Device Monitor icon, nothing happen...

Comment: @Hoo Okay .I understand your problem .Did you `FORMAT` ?  Actually I guess your `emulator.exe` corrupted .That's why have problem .

Comment: But why I can use real device to run?

Comment: @Hoo You will run this `AVD`

Comment: it runs after install HAXM installer and Android sdk tools.:)

Comment: @Hoo Glad to hear .Happy coding .Move Ahead

Answer (score 2):

Found the following solution.
Go to the following directory in your computer:

C:\Users.android\avd

Inside this directory you will find all files and directories with the definition and content of your avd machines-

Now do the basic troubleshooting steps:

-check if the avd directory exists and if it contains a file with the name "sdcard.img".

-if the file exists, try to rename it (to check if its locked) and then go to eclipse and ask to create a new sd card.

-if it fails, try to create manualy a file with that name to check premissions.

good luck