# Emulator doesn't launch

Tags: android, emulation

When I'm trying to launch my emulator, I'm getting this type of error message in my Event log:

> 19:26:47 ProcessNotCreatedException: Error launching emulator: Cannot
>   run program
>   "C:\Users\Tadas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe":
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Why this problem occured?

Comment: Well, "The system cannot find the file specified" seems obvious... Try opening a file browser and checking that location

Comment: I have already checked the location, there is an emulator file called emulator -x86 and lib folder

Comment: If you type `dir C:\Users\Tadas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe` in the command console, what does that show you?

Comment: Clearly your file is not there anymore. Which folder did you find the emulator -x86?

Comment: C:\Users\Tadas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools In this one folder i found emulator -x86

Comment: Looks like your emulator.exe has been removed. You need to reinstall it. Consider follow my recommended steps below.

Comment: check link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417842/avd-not-running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly find that if you file is there or not by running the below in the Command Console.

```
dir C:\Users\Tadas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe
```

If you don't find it there, that means the file has been removed. Then you might want to locate where your emulator is.

If you find it else where, go to `Android Studio->File->Project Structure->SDK Location` to enter the new path (note include till where the `sdk` directory, without the `tools` directory shown).

If you can't find it else where. Then you might need to reinstall it. Go to `Android Studio->Tools->Android->SDK Manager->SDK Tool tab` to install the needed emulator.

Comment: Thank You. I will inform you after I reinstall it.

Comment: Im having new Problem:

Comment: Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM must be updated (version 1.1.1 < 6.0.1).

Comment: Im getting this error when im launching the emulator. HAXM is updated, atleast  SDK tool section showing like that.

Comment: Perhaps you could reinstall the HAXM using the same step above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Two items to check, a corrupted emulator.exe, and your pc is not able to load it due to low memory.

Answer (score 1):

You may not missing the only *emulator.exe* but the whole *tools* folder. So lookup for tools folder inside **SDK** dir. If it's missing find another **SDK** and copy it's tools folder into you original **SDK** folder.